# How does the input field with type of number work?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to check if an input field with the type of number is empty, and I already found how to do it but I can't understand why

I found an answer which taught me how to do it, but not why, and I really want to understand how it works in the background

I know that if I use the length method it won't work since it is used to look for a string, but if I leave it empty and click on the button, what will be sent, a `null` value, an `undefined` or anything else?

here is the code I used to check:

```
if (!value) {
  //do work here
}
```

Comment: Integers are 'truthy' in JavaScript, so you're essentially checking `if ([not] true)` when the input is a positive integer(s), and `if ([not] false)` when the value is empty. Thus your check will determine whether a number is passed in or not. The actual *restriction* of a number type happens in `input type="number"` on the HTML side.

Comment: Just a point of clarification: *non-zero* integers, or non-zero numbers of any sort, are truthy, but 0 is falsy (and so is `NaN`).

Comment: so when i leave the field empty, it sends an undefined value which is considered as falsy? @ObsidianAge

Comment: Actually, even when you say that an input is `type="number"`, you're getting numbers back in string form. So you'll have an empty string (`''`) when the field is empty. It wouldn't hurt to test for `null` and `undefined` too, just in case -- those values can be set programmatically to make an input field blank.

Comment: Oh, and once you're sure it isn't `null` or `undefined`, `value.length === 0` is perfectly fine to test too, since it will be a string.